# Can't get sound from midi keyboard

Tags: keyboard, jack, midi

I have an AKAI-LPK25 and want to connect it to ZynAddSubFx (which i downloaded from sofwarecenter). I run the Qjackctl and connect Zynaddsubfx output to system, clicking on the keys of Zyn works fine and i get sound. But under Jack connections my real LPK25 keyboard is listed under ALSA and not under MIDI windows (where also Zynaddsubfx exists) so that i can't connect my keyboard to Zynadd. What can i do to connect them togethear? I am running on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install `a2jmidid` and use it to proxy the ALSA and MIDI interfaces, so they may be connected.